# jQuery Chosen multiple controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have dynamically generated Chosen elements (cloned from first of them) on my page. But when I click one of cloned Chosen elements looks like it open first one drop-down. So all of cloned elements works via first one.

How can I dissociate cloned elements from first one and force them work separately?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. You must simply call `.chosen()` when append new dynamic element to the **DOM**.

```
var new_element=$(my_select).clone(false);
$(document.body).append(new_element)
$(new_element).chosen();
```